# What is arcpy.cim?

Tags: arcpy, symbology, arcgis-pro, cartographic-information-model

In the help for ArcGIS Pro 2.4's [Python CIM access](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm) there is "**Example 3: Modify layer symbology**" which has this code:

```
# Reference a project, map, and layer using arcpy.mp
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('current')
m = p.listMaps('Trail Routes')[0]
lyr = m.listLayers('Loops')[0]

# Return the layer's CIM definition
cim_lyr = lyr.getDefinition('V2')

# Modify the color, width and dash template for the SolidStroke layer
symLvl1 = cim_lyr.Renderer.Symbol.Symbol.SymbolLayers[0]
symLvl1.Color.Values = [250, 250, 40, 50]
symLvl1.Width = 8
ef1 = symLvl1.Effects[0]    #Note, deeper indentation
ef1.DashTemplate = [20, 30]

# Modify the color/transparency for the SolidFill layer
symLvl2 = cim_lyr.Renderer.Symbol.Symbol.SymbolLayers[1]
symLvl2.Color.Values = [140, 70, 20, 20]

# Push the changes back to the layer object
lyr.setDefinition(cim_lyr)
```

I think the documentation was written before finalization of ArcGIS Pro 2.4, where this functionality was introduced for the first time, because it seems to contain capitalization errors, and is missing a key line that I picked up by watching a [YouTube video from Esri's 2019 Developer Summit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=8wgt8bKD0Ww).

This code should work correctly:

```
# Reference a project, map, and layer using arcpy.mp
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('current')
m = p.listMaps('Trail Routes')[0]
lyr = m.listLayers('Loops')[0]

# Return the layer's CIM definition
cim_lyr = lyr.getDefinition('V2')

# Modify the color, width and dash template for the SolidStroke layer
symLvl1 = cim_lyr.renderer.symbol.symbol.symbolLayers[0]
symLvl1.color.values = [250, 250, 40, 50]
symLvl1.width = 8
symLvl1.effects = [arcpy.cim.CIMGeometricEffectDashes()]
ef1 = symLvl1.effects[0]    #Note, deeper indentation
ef1.dashTemplate = [20, 30]

# Modify the color/transparency for the SolidFill layer
symLvl2 = cim_lyr.renderer.symbol.symbol.symbolLayers[1]
symLvl2.color.values = [140, 70, 20, 20]

# Push the changes back to the layer object
lyr.setDefinition(cim_lyr)
```

The missing line (which I added in the above) is:

```
symLvl1.effects = [arcpy.cim.CIMGeometricEffectDashes()]
```

Is `arcpy.cim` an undocumented ArcPy module, function or class, and to learn about it, is reading the [ArcGIS.Core.CIM Namespace](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/sdk/api-reference/#topic44.html) .NET SDK API Reference the only way?

I have reported what I believe to be the documentation error using the link at the bottom of that help page.  I have also asked this question at GeoNet as https://community.esri.com/message/883740-what-is-arcpycim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My question was [answered by Jeff Barrette of Esri at GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/message/883740-what-is-arcpycim#comment-883645):

> The arcpy.cim module is necessary for CIM support but we intentionally
>   did not document it.  We hope that with future builds we will provide
>   helper functions that will make it easier and more reliable to create
>   new objects.

Jeff has also corrected the help page, ready for the next help publication, and provided some additional information accompanied by a warning:

> The missing line that you added is NOT required if the symbol already
>   has a dashed effect.  What the line did essentially was generate the
>   effect.  This is something you need to be very careful about doing. 
>   The Developer Summit plenary video does show the line you added.  That
>   particular example is a simple use case but due to the complexity of
>   object creation where new objects have dependencies on addition
>   objects, it is easy to create objects that may fail in the
>   application.